# how do I store the output of a cut -c command into a variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, variables, unix, cut

I have a file name like

> Incoming_file_180420053826.csv

where **180420** represents the date and **053826** represents time.
I have used `echo $( cut -c 15-20 $filename )` to retrieve the date, but I'm unable to store that output date in a variable.

Comment: Reading your posting again, it gets unclear what you are looking for. If the variable `filename` contains the string `Incoming_file_180420053826.csv` (you did not write this), the `cut` command operates on the **contents** of this file, not on its name. I suggest that you add to your question a complete, reproducible example (including setting the variable `filename` and doing the `echo` command).

Comment: to store the output of a command you need to state the variable name before that command. In your example this becomes: mydate=$(echo $filename | cut -c 15-20 ); mytime=$(echo $filename | cut -c 21-26 ). Try this then echo each variable to see that it is what you want. Sorting this is another story as your date is in the format ddmmyy, would have been better with yymmdd, the time should sort better. Cannot you siply sort your many Incoming files by their creation date instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
my_var="$( echo  $filename | cut -c 15-20 )"
```

Demo:

```
$filename=Incoming_file_180420053826.csv 
$my_var="$( echo  $filename | cut -c 15-20 )"
$echo $my_var 
180420
$
```

Comment: For clearness, please remove the preceding `$` in the lines being posted. I know that this is your command prompt, but if someone is not aware of it, he might also type the $ in his script....

Comment: A small optimization: At least for bash, it could be written more succinctly by avoiding the pipe and do a `my_var=$(cut -c 15-20 <<<$filename)`. The OP tagged his question as _bash_ and _shell_, so I don't know whether he wants a solution which works in bash **or** (Posix) shell, or which works in bash **and** shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename=test.txt
aa=$( cut -c 1-6 $filename )
echo $aa
```

180420 180421 180422 180423 180424 180425

But I think you maybe just need first line, maybe this is what you need.

```
bb=$(head -1 $file|cut -c 1-6)
echo $bb
```

180420